# How to format a string in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

I need to format a string, but even if I copy a seemingly correct code, the CLIPS interpreter signals me an error.

(format nil "Integer:     |% ld|" 12)

“I expect the output of "Integer:     |12|" but the CLIPS interpreter signals me an error.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no space between the % character and the format flag. Also the character 'l' is not a valid format flag.

```
CLIPS> (format nil "Integer: |%d|" 12)
"Integer: |12|"
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!